# If $x:y=3:4$, find the ratio of $7x-4 : 3x+y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this question in an algebra book. Though it looks deceptively simple, I can't get my head around this question.

> If $x:y=3:4$, find the ratio of $7x-4 : 3x+y$.

The thing is, I can only frame one linear equation out of the given data; i.e., $4x-3y=0$.

> How can I solve for both $x$ and $y$ with this one equation?

Comment: Check the question, is it $7x-4y : 3x+y$ for e.g.?

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible :

- if $x=3$ and $y=4$, $(7x-4)/(3x+y)=17/13$

whereas

- if $x=6$ and $y=8$, $(7x-4)/(3x+y)=38/26$

and these values are not the same...

Check maybe the text of your exercise.